# Array TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am experimenting with arrays, and am reading the book "Beginning Ruby on Rails" by Steve Holzner. I made the program:

```
array = ['Hello', 'there', 1, 2]
puts array[1]
puts array[3]
puts array.length
array2 = Array.new
puts array2.length
array2[0] = "Banana"
array2[1] = 6
puts array2[0] + " " + array2[1]
puts array3.length
```

It doesn't do much, but when i run it i get the error

```
arrays.rb:9:in `+': can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError)
    from arrays.rb:9
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can't add a string and a integer (`Fixnum`), in this case you tried to add 6 to "Banana".

If on line 9 you did this:

```
puts array2[0] + " " + array2[1].to_s
```

You would get:

```
"Banana 6"
```

Comment: I'd add throwing an error here is a feature of a strongly typed language, of which Ruby is one example. PHP, a weakly typed language, would allow such chicanery.

Comment: @bernie It's more of a direct result of Ruby's type coercion rules, not its strong typing. For example, Float + Fixnum in Ruby is legal because Ruby knows how to coerce one type to the other. You could actually reopen Fixnum and add a `coerce` method that would make String + Fixnum legal as well.

Answer (score 4):

`array2[1]` is `6`, which is a Fixnum.  It doesn't know how to add itself to a string (which in this case is `Banana`.  If you were to convert it to a string, it would work just fine.

```
puts array2[0] + " " + array2[1].to_s
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is basically saying you cannot convert `array2[1]` (the value is a number, a type *Fixnum* in this case) into a *String* type. The way you would work around this is to convert the type into a *String* (this is for line 9 where the error occurs):

```
puts array2[0] + " " + array2[1].to_s
```

The array2[1].**to_s** converts the number into a String type.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this myself, but try replacing

```
puts array2[0] + " " + array2[1]
```

with

```
puts array2[0] + " " + array2[1].to_s
```

Comment: array2[0] is already a String type, you want to convert element 1 (array2[1]) as it holds the "6"

Comment: @Kevin Jalbert Yeah I saw it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to convert a FixNum expression into a string,

```
x=2
print (x+20).to_s + "\sbanannas"
```

Didn't know you could tack on the FixnNum#to_s method to those parens.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to add an integer(fixnum) and a string, which is something you can't do on ruby unless you explicitly cast the integer(fixnum) to a string. in your code `array2[0]`holds a string value "banannas" and `array2[1]` holds an integer(fixnum) value 1. so for your code too run correctly you need too cast the value in array2[1] to a string value.

you can change your code on line 9 to this:

```
puts array2[0] + " " + array2[1]._s
```